# CSS Pseudo Classes apply with external CSS, Regular class won't

Tags: html, css

I'm attempting to but together some stylized buttons together, and keep classes I'm using to do so in an external CSS sheet. My problem is that when I attempt to reference the class in my HTML code, the pseudo classes apply and the standard class will not.

My HTML code is

```
<body>
      <button class="buttonModifier"></button>
      <div class="buttonModifier"></div>
</body>
```

And then within my external .css sheet I have:

```
<style>

.buttonModifier{

    background-color:rgba(102,102,102,.6);  
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    border-radius:3px;
    background-image:url(images/playerButton.png);




}

.buttonModifier:hover{

    background-color:rgba(102,102,102,1);   
    background-image:url(images/playerButton.png);

}

.buttonModifier:active{

    position:relative;
    top:1px;
    background-color:rgba(102,102,102,.6);  

}


</style>
```

When I go to my HTML page, the class .buttonModifier isn't applying to my HTML elements that are specified to that class, yet the ":hover" and ":active" properties still apply when I mouse-over or click on the  or on the button. I would think that my .css sheet were linked correctly, as the pseudo classes are applying, yet the main class ".buttonModifier" isn't.

Comment: try adding button .buttonModifier, div .buttonModifier {//ur css}

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/NXrrW/ this alone works fine.

Comment: @Above: The code works just fine when it's within the same document, but only pseudo classes apply from an external CSS. If I have to put it directly on my HTML page I can do that just fine, but I'm looking to not have to paste that in every time I make a new page, hence using an external style sheet.